# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found Cannot find file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm new to coding and I'm trying to follow along with a training video.  I've followed the steps and I cannot read from a file that I have saved to the project folder.  Any help will be appreciated.

```
package testresults;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestResults {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    try
    {
        Scanner scFile = new Scanner(new File ("marks.txt"));       
        while(scFile.hasNext())
        {
            String line = scFile.nextLine();

            Scanner scLine = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter("#");

            String first = scLine.nextLine();
            String second = scLine.nextLine();
            double score = scLine.nextDouble();
            boolean passFail = scLine.nextBoolean();   
            scLine.close();

            System.out.println(first.charAt(0) + ". " + second + " " + score 
             + " " + passFail);
        }
        scFile.close();

    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("We messed up");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where is the file stored?  Have you tried an absolute path?

Comment: Which line gives you the exception?

Comment: Ok, so you read in __one single line__ as `line` and then you try to read two lines out of that single line? How should that work? Changing the delimiter doesn't affect the `nextLine()` method. Use `next()` for that.

Comment: As @Tom stated: the problem is within the way you use the scanner. It has nothing to do with the file itself. The title of your question is misleading.

Comment: The file is stored in the project folder and its a notepad document.

Comment: the error message reads: at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
 at testresults.TestResults.main(TestResults.java:22)

Comment: why does the instruction use it that way and its not working for me?

Comment: wow, using the next method fixed the issue.  Thank you all for your help.  This worked out better than I imagined. Hope to be as proficient as you all one day.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a wrong scanner method to read data as tokens with delimiters. 
`next()` Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern

`nextLine()` Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the inputthat was skipped.This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any lineseparator at the end

So nextLine() does not consider delimiter. In your case, the code `String second = scLine.nextLine();` will not evaluate as the line is already consumed.

Use the `next()` instead of `nextLine()`. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue here is how you use the Scanner. You're reading a single line from your file using `String line = scFile.nextLine();`, which is fine. Then you try to separate the elements from the line using another `Scanner` instance, which is generally a good idea as well, but your issue is in this block:

```
Scanner scLine = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter("#");

String first = scLine.nextLine();
String second = scLine.nextLine();
```

You're creating a new instance of Scanner and change its delimiter to separate elements from the `line` value. But you then call `nextLine()` twice, but `nextLine()` does not use your specified delimiter.

Let's check the [implementation of `nextLine()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/8cc500af2454/src/share/classes/java/util/Scanner.java#l1578) (from OpenJDK Java 8):

```
public String nextLine() {
    ...
    String result = findWithinHorizon(linePattern, 0);
    if (result == null)
        throw new NoSuchElementException("No line found");
    ...
}
```

The pattern used is `linePattern` which comes from the [`linePattern()` method](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/8cc500af2454/src/share/classes/java/util/Scanner.java#l509). That method returns the [hard-coded pattern `"\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085]`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/8cc500af2454/src/share/classes/java/util/Scanner.java#l498) and not your specified delimiter.

You need to use the method `Scanner#next()` instead, which uses your delimiter to read the *next* token. A token is a data part enclosed within delimiters.

So your code should be:

```
Scanner scLine = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter("#");

String first = scLine.next();
String second = scLine.next();
```